# PyCharm 3.4 unittest subTest() does not fail

Tags: pycharm, unit-testing

There is option how to make a sub-test in python3 unittest. From documentation:

```
class NumbersTest(unittest.TestCase):

def test_even(self):
    """
    Test that numbers between 0 and 5 are all even.
    """
    for i in range(0, 6):
        with self.subTest(i=i):
            self.assertEqual(i % 2, 0)
```

If this is executed from command-line, it results as expected (and described in documentation): 3 fails (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests)).

But if I run it from PyCharm 3.4, test passes. I have configured Default test runner as Unittests. What should I configure in PyCharm to run the sub-test as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context manager unittest.subTest() is new in Python 3.4.

PyCharm 3.x does not support subTests yet. The support was added to PyCharm 4.0, see

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/#Subtests.